# Дребежит голос на мобильном телефоне E173 + Asterisk 13 + chan_dongle

Tags: asterisk, модемы, шлюз, 3g

**Имеется:**
OpenWRT +
Asterisk 13.9 + PJSIP и chan_dongle +
Huawei E173 (11.126.15.00.209) в розлоченом режиме
кодеки ulaw alaw и gsm

**Суть:**
Почему-то во время звонка на моб. телефоне голос мненого похож как на рации, также на пару секунд перерывается связь. В чем может быть проблема? Звук слишен в обе стороны. Пробовал сменить кодеки - нету результатов.

Спасибо

Comment: У меня такое было в двух случаях: 1. Не хватало процессорной мощности на сервере Астера "load average" (дисковую подсистему тоже надо глянуть ) 2. Не хватало ширины интернет канала на астере.(либо плохое качество с потерями пакетов)

Comment: Спасибо @VladVetrov за ответ. 
1) На данный момент в качестве сервера использую роутер tp-link tl-wr1043nd rev 4 и вижу .что проц есть 750 MHz и RAM 64 MB 
Load average: 0.03 0.03 0.00 1/82 6938

Comment: Я думаю это не должно быть так критично

2) Хм для этих целей использую WIFI что имеет где-то 5 мб/c скорости интернета. Как-то маловереятно 

Можно ли проверить кодеки или как-то протестировать канал в астериске? Спасибо

Comment: также могу предоставить ссылку к роутеру https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/tp-link/tp-link_tl-wr1043nd_v4

Comment: Какая у вас плотность звонков? сколько пиров зерегено? мне кажется ваш роутер-сервер астериска не справляется с нагрузкой

Comment: Спасибо Тебе @VladVetrov за помощь. На данный момент использую сейчас asterisk только в экспериментальних целях поэтому у меня только один тестовый активний пир (в pjsip - endpoint). В утилите `top` в консоле вижу только `Load average: 0.03 0.05 0.01 1/79 4907` думаю что это не связано с произведительностью в данный момент. Поэтому не могу понять с чем эта проблема связана

Comment: это может быть проблемой с донглем? Хотя конечно в эхо он работает здорово (как с мобилы так из sip). Спасибо

Comment: Я бы попробовал во время установленного соединения с абонентов снять значения load average, но не сразу, а подождав пару минут. Еще надо бы помониторить нагрузку на дисковую подсистему во время вызова (команда iotop).

Comment: Спасибо @VladVetrov вам за поддержку. Проблема оказалась банальная что в настройках догла для `rxgain` и `txgain` была выставленая слишком большая громкость, что и создавала эффект хрипа. Спасибо за участие Вам

Comment: Ну хорошо что решилось. Всякое бывает, надо будет запомнить и этот вариант событий =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась банальная что в настройках догла (`/etc/asterisk/dongle.conf`) для `rxgain` и `txgain` была выставленая слишком большая громкость, что и создавала эффект хрипа.